# Como transformar uma saída de uma query já em xml no Informix?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, informix

É possivel pegar uma saída qualquer de uma query direto do banco e
trazer o resultado já formatado em texto XML  ?

Isso utilizando banco de dados IBM Informix v11.50 e de modo nativo no banco de dados.

Onde ao invés do banco retornar um dataset com cada campo em seu formato irá retornar um TXT em XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir da vesão 11.10 do banco é possivel sim.
Para saber qual versão do banco você está utilizando, execute este SQL:

```
select dbinfo('version', 'full') from systables where tabid = 1;
```

Existem algumas funções especificas para isso, porém há limitações que para contorna-las pode ser um pouco trabalhoso e até depender de certas configurações no banco (SMARTBLOB spaces).

A função básica para isso é a `genxml()` onde ela vai retornar em apenas 1 linha todos os registros da query. Como esta função retorna uma LVARCHAR ela é limitada em 32kbytes o que pouco para um XML, portanto tem que tomar cuidado como vai selecionar muitos dados senão terá o erro 8368 (veja no final do exemplo abaixo), para contornar este problema você ter que utilizar outras funções .

Uma lista das funções existentes (que você irá encontrar detalhes nos links dos manual abaixo): *genxml, genxmlelem, genxmlschema, genxmlquery, genxmlqueryhdr,  extract, extractvalueclob, existsnode, idsxmlparse.*

Para referencia em uma versão mais antiga do banco consulte este link[da versão 11.50](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/topic/com.ibm.xml.doc/ids_xp.htm)
Para referencia na versão mais atual do banco consulte este link [da versão 12.10](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.xml.doc/ids_xp.htm?lang=en)

Exemplo de um sql executado no dbaccess.

```
database sysmaster;
Database selected.

select genxml(systables, "tabela") from systables where tabid = 1 ;
genxml  <tabela tabname="systables" owner="informix                        " pa
        rtnum="1048800" tabid="1" rowsize="497" ncols="24" nindexes="2" nrows="
        245.0000000000000000" created="21/11/2011" version="65539" tabtype="T"
        locklevel="R" npused="9.0000000000000000" fextsize="32" nextsize="32" f
        lags="0" type_xid="0" am_id="0" pagesize="4096" ustlowts="2011-11-21 11
        :23:13.00000" secpolicyid="0" protgranularity=" "/>
1 row(s) retrieved.


select genxmlclob(systables, "tabela") from systables where tabid = 1 ;
genxmlclob
<tabela tabname="systables" owner="informix                        " partnum="1048800" tabid="1" rowsize="497" ncols="24" nindexes="2" nrows="245.0000000000000000" created="21/11/2011" version="65539" tabtype="T" locklevel="R" npused="9.0000000000000000" fextsize="32" nextsize="32" flags="0" type_xid="0" am_id="0" pagesize="4096" ustlowts="2011-11-21 11:23:13.00000" secpolicyid="0" protgranularity=" "/>
1 row(s) retrieved.


select genxmlclob(systables, "tabela") from systables where tabid <=5 ;
genxmlclob
<tabela tabname="systables" owner="informix                        " partnum="1048800" tabid="1" rowsize="497" ncols="24" nindexes="2" nrows="245.0000000000000000" created="21/11/2011" version="65539" tabtype="T" locklevel="R" npused="9.0000000000000000" fextsize="32" nextsize="32" flags="0" type_xid="0" am_id="0" pagesize="4096" ustlowts="2011-11-21 11:23:13.00000" secpolicyid="0" protgranularity=" "/>
<tabela tabname="syscolumns" owner="informix                        " partnum="1048801" tabid="2" rowsize="157" ncols="10" nindexes="2" nrows="2778.0000000000000000" created="21/11/2011" version="65539" tabtype="T" locklevel="R" npused="30.0000000000000000" fextsize="32" nextsize="32" flags="0" type_xid="0" am_id="0" pagesize="4096" ustlowts="2011-11-21 11:23:13.00000" secpolicyid="0" protgranularity=" "/>
<tabela tabname="sysindices" owner="informix                        " partnum="1048802" tabid="3" rowsize="3323" ncols="15" nindexes="2" nrows="192.0000000000000000" created="21/11/2011" version="65539" tabtype="T" locklevel="R" npused="11.0000000000000000" fextsize="32" nextsize="32" flags="0" type_xid="0" am_id="0" pagesize="4096" ustlowts="2011-11-21 11:23:13.00000" secpolicyid="0" protgranularity=" "/>
<tabela tabname="systabauth" owner="informix                        " partnum="1048803" tabid="4" rowsize="77" ncols="4" nindexes="2" nrows="262.0000000000000000" created="21/11/2011" version="65539" tabtype="T" locklevel="R" npused="6.0000000000000000" fextsize="32" nextsize="32" flags="0" type_xid="0" am_id="0" pagesize="4096" ustlowts="2011-11-21 11:23:13.00000" secpolicyid="0" protgranularity=" "/>
<tabela tabname="syscolauth" owner="informix                        " partnum="1048804" tabid="5" rowsize="73" ncols="5" nindexes="2" nrows="109.0000000000000000" created="21/11/2011" version="65539" tabtype="T" locklevel="R" npused="3.0000000000000000" fextsize="32" nextsize="32" flags="0" type_xid="0" am_id="0" pagesize="4096" ustlowts="2011-11-21 11:23:13.00000" secpolicyid="0" protgranularity=" "/>
1 row(s) retrieved.

select genxml(systables, "tabela") from systables ;
 8368: Function (genxml) Buffer size exceeds maximum size.
Error in line 2
Near character position 49

Database closed.
```